# Error (Xcode): Framework not found MTBBarcodeScanner

Tags: ios, xcode

i'm new, what may cause this error?

Could not build the precompiled application for the device.
Error (Xcode): Framework not found MTBBarcodeScanner

Error launching application on iPhone X.

Comment: How did you include the framework in your project ?

Answer (score 2):

What I had to do is go to

Xcode => Runner => Build settings => Under linking => Double click "Other linker flags"

Delete these two

```
-framework
"MTBBarcodeScanner"
```

You may also have to delete these two

```
-framework
"qr_code_scanner"
```